# Why does the merge of 2 types with a shared property name not work when making a type with that property from the merged type?

Tags: typescript

```
type a = {
    a: number
    b: {d: string}[]
}
type b = {
    c : string
    b: {f: number}[]
}

type l = a & b

const ab: l = {a: 1, c: '', b: [{d: '', f:1}]}

const ac: l['b'] = [{ d: '', f: 1}]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDeBYAUFTsBcUB2ArgLYBGEATullCbkgCa4DOw5AlngOYC+A2gLrpu6UJBoJkVLAGMozVh05TMtZADNchUhT6C0wtCPDQANhLgAyGunTSA9nhaxVZxEhi4AjABoo03ADkAb6qvAyBwVAantz8BrYOTjD+UCa8ASQB-BJhUIxQQb4aUDF6QA)

After merging types `a` and `b` into type `l` why does `const ab` of type `l` work while `const ac` of type `l['b']` does not work?

i tried to write this code on vscode and got this error on const ac :

```
Type '{ d: string; f: number; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ d: string; }[] & { f: number; }[]'.
  Types of property 'pop' are incompatible.
    Type '() => { d: string; f: number; }' is not assignable to type '(() => { d: string; }) & (() => { f: number; })'.
      Type '() => { d: string; f: number; }' is not assignable to type '() => { d: string; }'.
        Type '{ d: string; f: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ d: string; }'.
          Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'f' does not exist in type '{ d: string; }'.
```

Why does type `l['b']` not contain the merged type `{d: string, f: number}[]` from type `{ d: string; }[] & { f: number; }[]` while it does on type `l`?

Comment: i understand, but somehow typescript will merge ``A[]`` and ``B[]`` into ``(A & B)[] `` if they are each passed to two properties with the same name into two different types like the example i wrote in my question: ``type a = {
    a: number
    b: {d: string}[]
}
type b = {
    c : string
    b: {f: number}[]
}

type l = a & b `` type ``l`` will actually accept both ``{d: string}[]`` and ``{f: number}[]`` as ``{d: string,  f: number}[]`` under the same property ``b`` of ``l`` type. Sorry i could'nt indent the code in the comment

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry! This seems to be a bug in TS reported at [ms/TS#42715](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42715), which might not be fixable without breaking a lot of other things.  Does that address the question now or am I still missing something?

Comment: ok, seems a pretty complex bug, i thought there was some kind of simple explanation or a mistake in my code. i Will just use the combination that works and not the bugged one, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#42715](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42715).  Apparently object properties whose type is an [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) [array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) receive [excess property warnings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) erroneously.  There was an attempt to fix it at [microsoft/TypeScript#43707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43707), but it apparently caused undesirable errors in real-world code bases, and so it was reverted according to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42715#issuecomment-833832270).  It doesn't look like it will be fixed anytime soon.

Note that intersected arrays behave in other undesirable ways, as per [microsoft/TypeScript#41874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874), so it's probably best to avoid such types where possible; you might be able to write your own utility type to perform a recursive intersection-like operation that behaves better with arrays.  For example:

```
type IntersectNestedArrays<T, U> =
    (T extends readonly any[] ? U extends readonly any[] ?
        { [I in keyof T]: MapInt<T[I], U[Extract<I, keyof U>]> } :
        MapInt<T, U> : MapInt<T, U>)

type MapInt<T, U> = ({
    [K in keyof (T & U)]:
    K extends keyof T ? K extends keyof U ?
    IntersectNestedArrays<T[K], U[K]> : T[K] :
    K extends keyof U ? U[K] : never
}) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;


type L = IntersectNestedArrays<A, B>;
/* type L = {
    a: number;
    b: {
        d: string;
        f: number;
    }[];
    c: string;
} */
```

It's probably out of scope for the question as asked to go into detail about how that type works, but the point is that the resulting type contains the `{d: string, f: number}[]` type you actually want, and then you completely circumvent the bug you ran into:

```
const ab: L =
    { a: 1, c: '', b: [{ d: '', f: 1 }] }; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUB2ArgLYBGEATmhibklACa4DOw5AlngOZQC+A2gF0UPFKEhQAQgmRV0AY2asOnWVBrIoAM1yFSFXoOEpR4aAEk8wCkwhzgAOQgsI9GOXKYQTADwAVADRQAKoAfAiqABS+UBAAHlZ49ExQ5BCY9AD2eAA2IFh4IIJQAPzBMfEQicmp6Vm5+YUCJaoYGnxmUBxQANYQIBmaUL4CuACymGAWwH7tAoFBfACi8R523maBvf2DoQJhPFDYLRjjk5Z+82FjE1MXwSEAlMZi0Ke3AffSEaitfADSnTwPT6AygUSgADJgg8RqoAXEEklgdshiUoPCKlVkaCgs1WlNrLYHE4rK53J4fL5-nNgtSrkNqYc4eVEcktji0Qs-k0dBAAG4UYQPFmVJEcTT6ADyaLo-0B2MGkpGUEljIOvIF5AA3MYTOIADLSAnkGx2RzOMkeLzeGCBCQhHUAegAVFAXlBDYgfhgcPhiGRtap1N7WuhGFAWOwuDrQxhtH69IHWvwBDGMAoI0po8IoM7HcY5FkWFh1J7VHRfQBGQIZgDktcC6j4dHD9cC8crvCaPC1UEdjqgGW6ngLReAWAz+r4tZItaaiGbDFwba0uE7PAEQA)